# Preposition used with the verb convert

Tags: prepositions

Which preposition is used with convert: to or into? For example, convert the requisition into (or to) a PO.

Comment: Either can be used. e.g. "*I've converted the measurements to metric*", "*I've converted my dollars into euros*".

Comment: [**HOW TO ASK A QUESTION:** Have you thoroughly searched for an answer *before* asking your question? Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you found and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and above all, it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer!](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: And tell us the context - because one answer may be more appropriate is some contexts and the other in different contexts.

Comment: Nothing wrong with the question. Perhaps, it could be asked on ELL, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Examining these pairings:

> - I converted my Euros into Dollars.
> - I converted my Euros to Dollars.
> - I converted my stocks into bonds
> - I converted my stocks to bonds
> - *I converted into Islam.
> - I converted to Islam.
> - *I converted my car into natural gas.
> - I converted my car to natural gas.
> - ?I converted my car from gasoline into natural gas.
> - I converted my car from gasoline to natural gas.

The examples marked with an asterisk do not work. The example with the question mark comes across oddly.  The rest of them are perfectly fine.

The reason why the asterisk examples don't work is because in those cases it sounds like you are now a religion and your car is a wisp of gas. The questionable example comes across oddly for the same reason, except that it sounds like your car used to consist of gasoline but now it is is going to be blown away in the next wind.

So, the answer is, with "convert" you can usually use "into" and "to" interchangeably, but not in all cases, and there may not be an explicable rule for recognizing those exceptional cases.

Answer (score 3):

As @p.s.w.g comments, either can be used in most contexts. Neither preposition is "better" than the other, and there's no difference in meaning. But as [this chart](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=converted%20it%20to,converted%20it%20into&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=) shows, *into* is still more common (though *to* is gradually catching up)...

[image]

---

That's the situation when *to convert* is used to mean *to change [something] **into** another form, substance, state, or product*. But when it means *to persuade or induce [someone] to adopt a particular religion, faith, or belief* (or simply *to adopt a religion*), it's almost always ***to***...

> [He was converted **to** Christianity](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22converted%20the%20pounds%20to%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22He%20was%20converted%20to%20Christianity%22&oq=%22He%20was%20converted%20to%20Christianity%22&gs_l=serp.3...23752.26159.3.26596.7.7.0.0.0.0.64.380.7.7.0...0.0...1c.1.18.psy-ab.Rnr6hKtQuTM&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.48572450,d.d2k&fp=340a5a63302ed31b&biw=1274&bih=930) (88,900 results in Google Books)
>    [He was converted into Christianity](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22converted%20the%20pounds%20to%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22He%20was%20converted%20into%20Christianity%22&oq=%22He%20was%20converted%20into%20Christianity%22&gs_l=serp.3...4516.4749.4.5119.2.2.0.0.0.0.100.159.1j1.2.0...0.0...1c.1.18.psy-ab.DVKyQOft7IU&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.48572450,d.d2k&fp=340a5a63302ed31b&biw=1274&bih=930) (28 results)